# Which is the best way to retrieve data from a remote server using concurrent calls?

Tags: concurrency, queue, bluebird

I'm working on retrieving data like Products, Orders eCommerce platforms such as BigCommerce, Shopify, etc., and save it in our own databases. To improve the data retrieval speed from their APIs, we're planning to use the Bluebird library.

Earlier, the data retrieval logic was like retrieving one page at a time. Since we're planning to make concurrent calls "n" number of pages will be retrieved concurrently.

For example, Bicommerce allows us to make up to 3 concurrent calls at a time. So, we need to make the concurrent calls so that we will not retrieve the same page more than once, and in case if a request failed then a request for that page will be resent.

What's the best way to implement this? One idea that strikes my mind is,

One Possible Solution - *Keep an index of ongoing requests in the database and update it on the API completion, so we will know which are unsuccessful.*

**Is there a better way of doing this?** Any suggestions/ideas on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit hard to help when the question is entirely conceptual with no code.  You are correct that somewhere you need to keep track of which requests have finished (and presumably their results), which are in process and which have not yet been sent.  I'm not sure what you really want help with.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hi, The question is, are there are any better solutions to this problem than the one I proposed

Comment: Well, there is no other concept than what you outline since you obviously have to keep track of what you've done, are in the process of doing and still have to do.  Conceptually, there is nothing else.  There are lots of possible implementations, but you don't seem to be asking about any detailed implementation since there is no code shown.  For example, whether or not you should be keeping track of this state in your database itself rather than just in an in-memory structure depends upon a number of things that are not disclosed here.